# google spanner and direct REST api calls

Tags: rest, emulation, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to use spanner emulator and I followed the instructions reported here:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator

to set it up.
I can use gcloud shell commands to create instance, database, tables, etc. and all works correctly.

But I am not able to use the Rest API directly to access the emulator, even though the google documentation reports it is possible not only to use google client libs to access the emulator, but also the rest api.

The first problem is that it is not clear if I have to use either the base URL
https://spanner.googleapis.com/
or
http://localhost:9020/

When I try with

http://localhost:9020/v1/parent=projects/local-project/instanceConfigs

I always returns and "Not found" message, which means the the Rest API ws are responding, but through gcloud commands I can manage such instance and project!

What am I wrong with?!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `http://localhost:9020` to access the emulator if you want to manually access the REST API, so you were on the right track there.

The URL should however be `http://localhost:9020/v1/projects/test-project/instanceConfigs` to list all instance configurations on the emulator. Use `http://localhost:9020/v1/projects/test-project/instances` to list all instances.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation :

> [Using the Cloud Spanner
> Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator)
>
> "The Cloud SDK provides a **local**, in-memory emulator, which you can
> use to develop and test your applications for free **without creating a
> GCP Project or a billing account**."

Therefore you should use the `localhost` (localhost:9020 for REST requests).